# Python-list expression output

Tags: python

```
a=["four", "score", "and", "seven", "years"][[0,2,3][1]]
```

print(a)

output is : `and`

What is the main logic of this expression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[0,2,3][1]` gives `2` which goes into `["four", "score", "and", "seven", "years"][2]` which in turn returns `and`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read such expressions from the inside out. Let's start with the original:

```
a = ["four", "score", "and", "seven", "years"][[0,2,3][1]]
```

`[0,2,3]` is a list, so you can access its elements with the `[]` operator. Since lists are zero-based, index `1` is the second item, which is `2`:

```
a = ["four", "score", "and", "seven", "years"][2]
```

Here, again, we're accessing a list element by its index. `2` refers to the third element, which is `"and"`.